# Order the nodes of a directed graph

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory

Given a directed graph $G$ and a number $k$, how can I order the nodes (let's say in an array) so that the distance between each two connected nodes is less than or equal to $k$?

Comment: That's an NP-complete problem, even for the undirected case, called *Bandwidth*.